Error Warning: Prop `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` did not match. Server: "" Client: ""
I am using next.js 16 with App Router and I want to enable Google reCaptcha and it works as I have implemented it, but I receive this error:
app-index.js:33 Warning: Prop `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` did not match. Server: "" Client: "(self.__next_s=self.__next_s||[]).push([\"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=KEY\",{}])"

In my project I have the file src/app/randompage/page.js with this function
'use client'
...
const handleRandom = () => {
    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
      grecaptcha.execute('Key', { action: 'submit' }).then(function (token) {
        console.dir(token);
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/random', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Recaptcha-Token': token
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            random_id: numericRandomId,
            comment: comment
          })
        })
          .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
              return response.json().then(data => Promise.reject(data.error));
            }
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(() => {
            setSuccessMessage('Randomed');
            setIsRandomed(true);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Not Randomed', error);
            setErrorMessage(error);
          });
      });
    });
  };

And in the same folder I have a layout.js with the google recaptcha script in the head. I wasn't able to put the script in the head of the page via next/head nor via metadata, that's why I chose to put it into the head with the strategy="beforeInteractive"
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import Script from 'next/script';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Random</title>
        <Script
          src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=Key"
          strategy="beforeInteractive"
        />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


It is working like this, but how can I get rid of the Error? And is this a proper way of implementing the reCaptcha without using a library?
Thanks in advance and best regards
